# ASP DropdownList doesn't work inside Bootstrap modal

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I'm very new to CSS styling and Bootstrap stuff, so I'm having too many issues during working on my job project.

Here I have an issue that prevents me to use `asp:DropDownList` control to be used inside a `Bootstrap modal`.

Actually what I'm trying to do is that I have a `button` called `New Ticket`, so when the user clicks on it a `Bootstrap modal` should popup includes in its body a `form panel` which has different controls like `Text Boxes`, `Labels` and `DropDownLists`. These `DropDownLists` are asp controls, and are being pre-populated in the C# Code-Behind.

Using this `form-panel` outside the modal is working perfectly, but trying to use it inside the modal brought me to this issue. Below is the error that occurs for me:

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.openticket_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'ddlServices_SelectedIndexChanged' and no extension method 'ddlServices_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.openticket_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is my `Modal code`:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-lg CenterForm">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading h4 text-primary text-center">
                                Token Registration
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="lblCallerID">Caller ID:</label>
                                        <asp:Label class="col-sm-2 control-label" ID="lblCallerID" runat="server" Text="66355356"></asp:Label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="txtCallerID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="lblServices">Complaint/Suggestion:</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <asp:DropDownList class="form-control" ID="ddlServices" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlServices_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="lblSeverity">Severity:</label>
                                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                                            <asp:DropDownList class="form-control" ID="ddlSeverity" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlServices_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                                        </div>
                                        <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="lblStatus">Status:</label>
                                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                                            <asp:DropDownList class="form-control" ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlServices_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                    <div class="form-group">

                                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="lblSubject">Subject:</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="txtSubject" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Subject"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="lblComments">Comments:</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="txtComments" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Comments" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" CssClass="label label-danger"></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Submit"></asp:Button>
                                            &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" Text="Cancel"></asp:Button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">New Ticket</button>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnNewTicket" OnClick="btnNewTicket_Click" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Open Ticket"></asp:Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is my try to trigger the modal using a `button`:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">New Ticket</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">New Client</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="glyphicon-user">Username</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: can you show SelectedIndexChanged event of ddlServices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not because bootstrap. It is because you are not handling event properly. You should have following in your code behind

```
protected void ddlServices_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // code to handle event
}
```

You also should have `AutoPostBack="true"` on dropdown list in mark up.

```asp
<asp:DropDownList class="form-control" ID="ddlServices" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlServices_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

I can also see you are calling same event handler `ddlServices_SelectedIndexChanged` which seems copy paste error to me. So keep that in account too.

Or if you dont want to handle this event then just remove `OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlServices_SelectedIndexChanged"` from your dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your code **is** stored in an .aspx page, and you **do** have a "ddlServices_SelectedIndexChanged" function declared in the related .aspx.cs file, here's my answer:

Go to the top of your .aspx page, and check that the details on the first line are correct.

I've had situations where I've had a beautifully working .aspx page (with a code-behind page), I've copied that .aspx to a second page, renamed it, but Visual Studio hasn't updated the values in the top line of my .aspx page.

For example, if your webpage is called `OpenTicket.aspx`, then you should have the following at the top of your .aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="OpenTicket.aspx.cs" Inherits="SomeNamespace.OpenTicket" %>
```

This explains why ASP.Net sometimes fails to find a code-behind function for one of the controls in an .aspx page.

Comment: P.S.  Going forward, stop using ASP.Net controls (and Postbacks to the server).  It's 2016...  ;-)